# Syntax of Solving polynomials

Tags: equation-solving

find the value of (x-a)^3 + (x-b)^3 + (x-c)^3 - 3(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) if a+b+c=3x

Please help me with the syntax for solving this problem

Comment: Look up `Solve`.  `Simplify[
 (x - a)^3 + (x - b)^3 + (x - c)^3 - 3 (x - a) (x - b) (x - c) /. 
  Solve[a + b + c == 3 x, x]
 ]`.  Also check `Factor`.

Answer (score 3):

`Maximize` with a constraint:

```
Maximize[{(x - a)^3 + (x - b)^3 + (x - c)^3 - 3 (x - a) (x - b) (x - c), a + b + c == 3 x}, x]
```

> {0, {x -> 1/3 (a + b + c)}}

Compare also with a messy output of maximization without the constraint (I'm not posting the output since it's messy):

```
Maximize[(x - a)^3 + (x - b)^3 + (x - c)^3 - 3 (x - a) (x - b) (x - c), x]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
FullSimplify[(x - a)^3 + (x - b)^3 + (x - c)^3 -   3 (x - a)*(x - b)*(x - c) /. x -> (a + b + c)/3]
```

0